# unix shell replace lowercase to uppercase in spcific lines (xsd tags)

Tags: shell, unix

I have file, with tags.
I need to change the strings in `""` from lowercase to uppercase, only where the line begins with `"<element name"`
for example:

```
<element name="product-info">
  <customer name="myname">
```

the needed output is:

```
<element name="PRODUCT-INFO">
  <customer name="myname">
```

Comment: `sed` can probably do that, but processing an XML file with regular expressions is dangerous. Are you sure that the documents to process will always have line breaks where you expect them?

Answer (score 1):

with sed, you can do the following :
`sed -ri 's/element name="(.*)"/element name="\U\1"/' your_file.xml`. 
It should not mess up the xml structure but be careful.

Comment: thank you. what is the command to do the same, but in case that there are more than one value in the tag? for example:       <element name="rdgl-rezerva" maxOccurs="unbounded">         should be changed to           <element name="RDGL-REZERVA" maxOccurs="unbounded">   and not to: 
     <element name="RDGL-REZERVA" MAXOCCURS="UNBOUNDED">

---

>

Comment: You can use the same expression with a small modification : `sed -ri 's/element name="([a-zA-Z-]+)"/element name="\U\1"/' your_file.xml`. Instead of taking any character between the quotation marks after element name it will only match letters (both lower and upper case) and -, so it will stop at the space before maxOccurs. Note that you might need to adapt a little bit the regex depending on what king of characters you can have in the string following element name.